# Last string in array of strings (parsed from strtok) has garbage

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok

I'm a little baffled here. In main:

```
int main() {
    char **symbols = (char **) malloc(3 * sizeof(char *)); // allocate 3 (char *)'s
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        symbols[i] = (char *)malloc(3); // allocate string of length 3

}
```

Then the user enters three string symbols, space delimited, on a single line:

```
111 010 101
```

I then parse this buffered string into an array of strings thusly:

```
void parseSymbols(char *line, int k, char **symbols) {
    // k == 3
    // Ignore leading spaces
    while (*line != '\0' && is_whitespace(*line))
            line++;

    char *p = strtok(line, " ");
    int cnt = 0;
    symbols[cnt++] = p;
    while (p) {
            p = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            symbols[cnt++] = p;
    }

    // Let's call this FOOBAR
    //for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    //        printf("%d. %s\n", i, symbols[i]);
```

}

Back in main, when I printf the 3 strings in symbols, I get this:

```
0. '111'
1. '010'
2. ' s'
```

But when I un-comment out the last two lines of parseSymbols, I get:

```
0. '111'
1. '010'
2. '101'
```

Why does the FOOBAR block "fix" my string array, and more importantly, how can I get parseSymbols working properly without having to print something to screen? Does symbols[2] need to be terminated with a '\0'? (But doesn't strtok do that for me?)

Comment: Please include a complete, runnable program in your question.

Comment: @NPE I don't think this is necessary. Everything that's needed to simulate the behavior is known...

Comment: It isn't necessary to cast the return value of malloc in C. Please ensure you're using a C compiler to compile C, *not* a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is the fact that you are causing a memory leak by assigning the resulting pointer of `strtok` to the symbol table. This is because you are just copying the reference to the next start of a token rather than copying the the resulting string in these lines: `symbols[cnt++] = p;`

Next you should make sure that you are not exceeding k by assinging results to your symbol table. Your code always writes NULL at the last position of your symbol table. As soon as you are parsing 3 symbols, you will write to unallocated memory causing undefined behavior.

I'd recommend to correct these things first and then try again.

Please note that strtok modifies your original buffer by replacing a delimiter with '\0' at the end of a token, so there is no need to copy the string. Please also note that strtok skips consecutive occurence of one of the delimiters. So your first loop can be replaced by a check if the length of the first token is >0 (or in other words the first byte of the resulting string is `!= '\0'`

Please note that C-Strings always need 1 byte more space than you want to store. This extra byte is used for '\0' Termination. In your example you are parsing chunks of 3 bytes while allocating only 3 bytes per chunk (where should be 4): `symbols[i] = (char *)malloc(3); // allocate string of length 3`

Comment: There is insufficient code to determine whether or not a memory leak occurs, and the explanation of the "memory leak" you have given is incorrect. It seems to me as though your last error is the most significant, so why mention it so late?